# Get Directory App_Data in A Static Helper File

Tags: asp.net

What am I supposed to write as CategoryPath to get the file in the App_Data folder?

Thanks

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for XMLHelper
/// </summary>
public static class XMLHelper
{
    public static string CategoryPath = "App_Data/Categories.xml";
    public static void InsertCategory(string categoryName, string moderator)
    {
        XElement cat = XElement.Load(CategoryPath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 AppDataDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"App_data")
```

Then just append the filename required. I haven't tested that code.

Hope it helps